# How to represent characters with combining characters as one

Tags: python, diacritics

I have the following combining diacritics characters

> [ọ́, ọ̀, ẹ̀, ẹ́]

. I'll like to keep them as one character when accessing them via string indexing in a string like

> "ọ̀rẹ̀"

for example current splits are:

```
s = "ọ̀rẹ̀"
 
 s[0] = ò  
 s[1] = . 
 s[2] = r 
 s[3] = è 
 s[4] = .
```

How do I get s[0] and s[1] to be one character instead of two as in original string?

Any ideas how to get this done in python?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. You seem to want to merge the "sets" of diacritics, collapsing identical marks to a single one but replacing conflicting marks with one of them?

Comment: It's also not clear why this would be useful.

Comment: @chepner, I added some more details to the question. Current string split, splits the combined diacritic into two instead of one. How can I keep the combined diacritics when doing a string split?

Comment: There is no single character for `ọ̀`. Only a limited number of pre-composed characters exist, such as `ó` for `o` + `´`. Having all possible characters in Unicode would make it unwieldy. The *displayed* characters are handled by the renderer displaying arbitrary combinations of base glyphs and diacritics.

Comment: @fenimi you need to split the string as graphemes rather than characters.

Answer (score 0):

A solution.

```py
import unicodedata

def combinedchars(string):
    result = []
    for char in string:
        if unicodedata.combining(char):
            result[-1] += char
        else:
            result.append(char)
    return(result)

s = "Borbá̭ra̭"
```

1. 

```
print(list(s))
```

gives

```
['B', 'o', 'r', 'b', 'á', '̭', 'r', 'a', '̭']
```

combining diacritical marks as separated chars.

2.

```
print(combinedchars(s))
```

gives the desired output

```
['B', 'o', 'r', 'b', 'á̭', 'r', 'a̭']
```

handling combining diacritical marks together with the preceding char.

Answer (score 0):

The reality is that many Latin script languages have letters that can not be represented by a single precomposed character. For instance "ọ̀rẹ̀" will require a minimum of five unicode codepoints.

Take the first letter **ọ̀**, it can be represented as the following character sequences: `U+00F2 U+0323`, `U+1ECD U+0300`, `U+006F U+0323 U+0300`, and `U+006F U+0300 U+0323`. All these sequences are canonically equivalent.

When working with languages that can not be represented wholly by precomposed characters, it is necessary to:

1. normalise all text to ensure it is all in a single normalisation form, either NFC or NFD.
2. work with extended grapheme clusters rather than characters.

A simple way to understand graphemes, is to think of them as what a user of that language would consider an individual letter. **ọ̀** would not be considered as a sequence of two or three characters, but as a single unit.

If we treat them as single characters:

```py
import unicodedataplus as ud
# normalise to retain consistent representation with data
s = ud.normalize("NFC", "ọ̀rẹ̀")
characters = list(s)
print(len(characters))
# 5
print(characters)
# ['ọ', '̀', 'r', 'ẹ', '̀']
```

But if we use graphemes instead:

```py
import regex
graphemes = regex.findall(r'\X', s)
print(len(graphemes))
# 3
print(graphemes)
# ['ọ̀', 'r', 'ẹ̀']
```

`\X` is a regular expression metacharacter that represents a single grapheme. This metacharacter isn't supported in **re**, so it is necessary to use either the **regex** or **pyicu** modules.

So for Yoruba, and various other languages, it is better to build functions and classes that operate on the grapheme level rather than the character level.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to create string from list characters just use `join` method

```py
x = ['ọ́', 'ọ̀', 'ẹ̀', 'ẹ́']
print("".join(x))
```